# Cant get my java class to display correct values (game) (getting all random damage to work, along with health)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, if-statement, random

I'm new to java and trying my hand at making a game. Here is what I have so far in my "combat class." Right now, if this was displayed with:

```
Combat fight1 = new Combat("Homeless Man", "Rusty Fork", 100, 110, 30);
```

I would get the output:

```
    Homeless Man hits you with a Rusty Fork, Dealing 81 damage!
You now have 0 HP left!
You hit Homeless Man With an attack using your null dealing 0 damage!
Homeless Man now has 100 HP left!
```

Is there any way that I can fix this to make it display the right values (random damage, health values, damage values, etc.)

I know that this is a lot of code (and work) to look through, so all help is greatly appreciated!

The code for the "Combat" class is below:

```
package Walking;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combat {
    
    //enemy
    String enemyName;
    String enemyItem;
    int enemyHP;
    int enemyMaxDam;
    int enemyMinDam;
    
    public int damageDelt;
    
    //player
    public int playerHP;
    public int playerMaxDam;
    public int playerMinDam;
    
    public int damageTaken;
    
    //player armor
    int clothes = 1;
    int tux = 0;
    
    //player weapon
    public String playerWeapon;
    int fists = 1;
    int bloody_Spoon = 0;
    
    
    public Combat() { 
        
    }
    
    public Combat(String _enemyName, String _enemyItem, int _enemyHP, int _enemyMaxDam, int _enemyMinDam) {
        enemyName = _enemyName;
        enemyItem = _enemyItem; 
        enemyHP = _enemyHP;
        enemyMaxDam = _enemyMaxDam;
        enemyMinDam = _enemyMinDam;     
    }
    
    public String getPlayerWeapon() {
        if(fists == 1) {
            playerMaxDam = 75;
            playerMinDam = 30;
            String playerWeapon = "Fists";
        }else {
            if(bloody_Spoon == 1) {
                playerMaxDam = 100;
                playerMinDam = 75;
                String playerWeapon = "Bloody Spoon";
            }
        }
        
        return playerWeapon;
    }
    
    public int getPlayerArmor() {
        if(clothes == 1) {
            playerHP = 1000;
        }else {
            if(tux == 1) {
                playerHP = 1100;
            }
        }
        
        return playerHP;
    }
    
    public int getDamageDelt() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        damageDelt = rand.nextInt(playerMaxDam = playerMinDam + 1) + playerMinDam;
        return damageDelt;
    }
    
    public int getDamageTaken() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyMaxDam - enemyMinDam + 1) + enemyMinDam;
        return damageTaken;
    }
    
    public void displayCombat() {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Will you:\n -Attack (1)\n -Consume Item (2) \n -Run (3)");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();
        if(userInput.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println(enemyName + " hits you with a " + enemyItem + ", Dealing " + getDamageTaken() + " damage!");
            System.out.println("You now have " + (playerHP - getDamageDelt()) + " HP left!");
            System.out.println("You hit " + enemyName + " With an attack using your " + playerWeapon + " dealing " + getDamageDelt() + " damage!");
            System.out.println(enemyName + " now has " + (enemyHP - getDamageDelt()) + " HP left!");
            
        }else {
            if(userInput.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("You managed to escape the fight with " + playerHP + " left!");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: as a suggestion, use just one Random

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Combat fight1 = new Combat("Homeless Man", "Rusty Fork", 100, 110, 30);
```

Initializes the following parameters: `enemyName`, `enemyItem`, `enemyHP`, `enemyMaxDam`, and `enemyMinDam`.

```
Homeless Man hits you with a Rusty Fork, Dealing 0 damage!
You now have 0 HP left!
You hit Homeless Man With an attack using your null dealing 0 damage!
Homeless Man now has 100 HP left!
```

Contains invalid values because the following variables were never initialized: `damageTaken`, `damageDelt` (used multiple times), and `playerWeapon`.

To fix `damageTaken` and `damageDelt`, all you need is to call the functions you created to generate random damage value. To fix `playerWeapon` you'll need to figure out how and where you need to provide a String value for it.

Comment: alright, I figured out damageTaken and damageDelt, but i'm having trouble with playerHealth and playerWeapon. I updated the code, along with the output.

Comment: Not sure how to fix `playerWeapon`. One way is to create an array of weapons and then use a random function to provide the index location in the array to select a weapon.  As for `playerHealth`, you need to store the remaining health after each attack:  `playerHealth = playerHealth - damageTaken;` Something like that.

Assuming you start with 100 HP and take 19 points of damage after one turn: `playerHealth = 100 (initial HPs) - 19 (damageTaken) which will be 81 HP left.